# Create network files from "classic" dataframe in R - igraph

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

My goal is to develop a network visualization in R, starting from a "classic" data frame. I thus have to create two files: nodes and links.
My current data set looks like this:

```
Driver   Insurance_taker  Counterparty1    Counterparty2   Counterparty3  Counterparty4   Counterparty5
Allan    Steven           NA               Patrick         Oliver         Jean             William
Ana      Anastasia        Max              Pierre          Jack           Sam              NA
```

Sample data (Please note that there are multiple NAs in the data):

```
mydata <- data.table(Driver=c("Allan", "Ana"),
      Insurance_taker = c("Steven", "Anastasia"), 
      Counterparty1= c(NA, "Max"),
      Counterparty2= c("Patrick", "Pierre"),
      Counterparty3= c("Olivier", "Jack"),
      Counterparty4= c("Jean", "Sam"),
      Counterparty5= c("William",NA))
```

My goal is to have one file called "nodes.csv" like:

```
Names      Type
Allan      Driver
Ana        Driver
Steven     Insurance_taker
Anastasia  Insurance_taker
...        ...
```

I have managed to get this file, but I also want to create another file (called "links" let's say) that would look like this:

```
From        To         Weight       Type
Patrick     Allan      30           witness1_driver
Allan       Steven     20           car_driver
....        ...        ...          ....
```

The weights will be determine according to the relationship type (eg witness1_driver => weight = 30)
Any help would be really much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. In terms of the `nodes.csv` where is the Person's **Type** coming from or are you trying to derive it? And what do NA's mean? Should they be kept in the network or discarded?

Comment: The person's Type is coming from the column name of mydata. I managed to get this file. My problem is really to get the "links.csv". Thanks a lot @emilliman5

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to melt `mydata`. Here is one option:

```
melt(mydata, id.vars = "Driver", varying=names(mydata)[-1])

# Driver        variable     value
# 1:  Allan Insurance_taker    Steven
# 2:    Ana Insurance_taker Anastasia
# 3:  Allan   Counterparty1        NA
# 4:    Ana   Counterparty1       Max
# 5:  Allan   Counterparty2   Patrick
# 6:    Ana   Counterparty2    Pierre
# 7:  Allan   Counterparty3   Olivier
# 8:    Ana   Counterparty3      Jack
# 9:  Allan   Counterparty4      Jean
# 10:    Ana   Counterparty4       Sam
# 11:  Allan   Counterparty5   William
# 12:    Ana   Counterparty5        NA
```

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks a lot. However, I get the error "Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped ". Not sure what it means

Comment: I suspect you some data in a column that is not identical across groups and so is getting dropped. If you can post `dput(head(mydata))` we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late answer. IT appears that melt is not even working since it's giving me NA in the "value" column

Comment: That's because you have NAs in the original dataframe. I left them because you did not specify what to do with them